# Git wouldn't allow me to pull from only one of the branches

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project with another developer. On a dev server, we have a repository with two branches:

1. master
2. dev

We've set up our remote repositories independently so that I pull with

`git pull ltarasiewicz dev`

while another developer pulls with

`git pull another_name dev`

Naturally, the remotes point to the same repository.

All have been good so far, but now I am not allowed to pull from the `dev` branch. I receive the following message from git:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

However, I can still pull from master with `git pull ltarasiewicz master`.

What is the problem here, and why has it appeared suddenly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not set your user name and email. You cannot use git unless you supply this info.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Once you set this info you will be able to pull content.

There are several levels for configuration.

- `--global` will add this info will be to your '~/.gitconfig' file (under users/ in windows machine).
- `--local` will set it only for the current repository
- `--system` will set it in OS level (usually you wish to avoid setting it there

#### Verify that the settings exist

`git config -l`

> Git use this info during commits and this is the only settings you **MUST** set before using git.

If you think you have already set it up and its still not working, edit the config file and verify that its there.